# How to show opening file can cause issues in IIS with lots of requests?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a legacy asp.net application that I need to maintain. I noticed a file being read each time a request is made (we could have about a 1000 requests per second). The load method of XmlDocument is used to read the file.

Although I do not see any locking issues (I have seem some posts where it has been discouraged to use XmlDocument.Load()), I feel that all this I/O with the file is causing our application to slow down when run for several days.

My question is how can I prove this could be a problem? Are there any diagnostics I could take to prove we should not be doing this?

Comment: Isn't a profiler the best tool to show you for what reason every second is consumed?

Comment: Profiler aside, can I answer this theoretically? Surely lots of requests on a file (even though I do not see locking issues) is not the correct way?